# couple slim redirection to index.php with domain redirection

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, slim

I have an application with slim and I would like to redirect to a new domain (like the www to non-www but at this time it is a completely different domain). I don't know how to do that, the rules makes redirections like

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.exampledomain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ www.example-domain.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

www.exampledomain.com -> www.example-domain.com/index.php

I don't have control on the exampledomain.com because it is a mail server managed by orange and example-domain.com is managed by ovh (we own both domains).

thanks by advance !

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution by adding rewrite rules on domain

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example-domain.com
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.exampledomain.com
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.example-domain.com/$1 [NC]
```